SQL Server 2017 not recognizing Oracle driver for Linked server
I would like to connect from my SQL Server 2017 to an Oracle database via Linked server. I installed the Oracle driver from Oracle-Client-for-Microsoft-Tools-64-bit.exe, but the driver does not appear in the Provider list under Linked server. Rebooted the server, but still no help. What am I missing? I only installed the Oracle driver from the Oracle Client installer package as I thought I don't need the other parts.

Linked server uses OleDb, and the Oracle OleDb provider isn't in that package.  It's only the ADO.NET driver and low-level Oracle client (OCI.dll), which is what's needed for most other Microsoft server tools.
To install the OleDb provider, use the ODAC XCopy package here.

Yes, indeed the OleDB Provider is needed from the ODAC package, correct, thank you. On the link above I only found the 12c version, I need 19c. I found it here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdeploy-downloads.html

Thanks.  I updated the link.
